# How do I enable the ASP.NET Role Manager in Linqpad?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linqpad

I have a code snippet in LINQPad which contains this line of code:

```
employees = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Employee");
```

which of course promptly fails with the `The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.` error. This makes sense as in LINQPad I do not have a web.config file to enable the Role Manager in.

How do I enable it for a connection in LINQPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINQPad 5 Beta now provides the ability to supply query specific app.config files. I was able to enable the ASP.Net Role Provider by copying the `roleManager` and `connectionStrings` sections of my larger application's web.config.